# python is "self" required on variable in function?

Tags: python, object, self

lets say I have a `class myArithmetics` and two functions within the class. The first function is  called `find_sum()` and the second is `is_max()`

```
class myAirthmetics

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def find_sum(self):
        numb = 15
        self.sum = 15 + numb

    def is_max(self):
        if self.sum > 20:
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("no")
```

My question is: Does the variable `numb` need to be `self.numb`? Since `numb` is not being accessed/used outside of the function `find_sum()`, it should not need to have `self.` ?

The only variables that require `self` are variables that are being accessed outside of their function?

Comment: Assign to `self` if you want to create an *instance attribute*

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, if you only want to use that variable in the scope of that function, there is no need for `self`.

P.S. I advise against naming a variable `sum` as that is a built-in function.

Comment: So would it be considered "best practice" to not include self on that variable? Or should I put it on?

Comment: It is definitely best practice to not include self if it is not needed.

Comment: If you *do* include self, then the variable is retained by the instance which might cause trouble later.

Comment: Actually, `sum` as an attribute is fine, that's the *beauty of namespaces*

Comment: I know it will run fine I just consider it bad practice.